# How to not repeat word in \index

Tags: packages, indexing, code, imakeidx

To make index I have to write word two times,

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
This will not print \index{anything} !!! 
However it will make an entery in Index. 
To print the word in text and index you need to write word \index{word}.
\printindex
\end{document}
```

To make an index for we need to write `word \index{word}`. I find it redundant.

Is there any way (package or code) to just write `\index{word}`?

Comment: You can define `\newcommand{\iindex}[1]{#1\index{#1}}` and then you type `\iindex{word}`

Comment: Getting lot of error "Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. \newcommand{\iindex}[#1]" . Please post full working example. Thanks

Comment: Please, see the edited comment. no `#` in brackets.

Comment: Now it works. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new command (eg `\iindex`) with one argument and use this argument to call `\index` and to print it on the text.

```
\newcommand{\iindex}[1]{#1\index{#1}}
```

and then you simply type `\iindex{word}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\newcommand{\iindex}[1]{#1\index{#1}} %%This is new command
 %%%and then you type \iindex{word}

\begin{document}
This will not print \index{anything} !!! 
However it will make an entry in Index. 
To print the word in text and index you need to write word \index{word}. 
Or \iindex{word} single.
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: if you write "word \index{word}." you will get a space before the period.  shouldn't be *any* space between the term being indexed and the `\index{...}` entry.  (the `\iindex` definition takes care of that worry.)